# javascript not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox

I have a master page which is having Javascript code which looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function ClientPrint(str)
    {  
              alert('before');
              PrintControl.RawPrint(str);            
              alert('after');

    }       
</script>
```

And the child form is calling this Javascript by the code

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "jcr", "ClientPrint('" & StrFinalBill & "')", True)
```

This code is working absolutely fine in IE but not in anyother browser in Firefox error console I’m getting this error “printcontrol is not defined”.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Is PrintControl an ActiveX component?

Answer (score 0):

IE supports refering to a node via its id. for firefox and other browsers use -

```
function ClientPrint(str)
{  
          alert('before');
          var PrintControl = document.getElementById(controlId); 
          PrintControl.RawPrint(str);            
          alert('after');

}
```

Comment: I tried but still no luck, i put alert after var line but it is not getting executed.

Comment: can u add a check to see if PrintControl is null. Also what is PrintControl